# Error 335544421. connection rejected by remote interface

Tags: java, jdbc, firebird, jaybird

I have the code

```
package com.redsoft.company.dao;

import org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class AbstractDao {
    private static final String USER = "root";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "root";
    private static final String URL = "jdbc:firebirdsql:localhost/3050:D:\\dev\\mycompany\\COMPANY.FDB";

    public AbstractDao() throws Exception {
        initConnection();
    }

    private void initConnection() throws Exception {
        Class.forName("org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver");
        DriverManager.registerDriver(new FBDriver());
        System.out.println(URL);
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASSWORD);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        AbstractDao abstractDao = new AbstractDao();
    }
}
```

When I run main method I get error

> Exception in thread "main" org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBSQLException: 
>   GDS Exception. 335544421. connection rejected by remote interface

Firebird version 3.0.3
Jaybird version 2.2.5

Comment: root/root is quite weird Firebird login/password on MS-Windows machine...

Comment: thank you, i try different variant's url and only for that i can get the above error

Comment: Which version of Jaybird are you using? Also note: you should **not** call `DriverManager.registerDriver` yourself; that method is to be called by JDBC drivers only, not for client applications. You shouldn't even need to call `Class.forName("org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver")` if you're using Jaybird 2.2 or higher.

Comment: If I use modern format url (jdbc:firebirdsql://localhost:3050/D:\dev\mycompany\COMPANY.FDB) I get error connection rejected by remote interface

Comment: Also, make sure you post your actual code. The code as shown will result in a `error: cannot find symbol` for `url`.

Comment: The problem with your code is that the URL is defined as `" jdbc:firebirdsql:..."`. Note that presence of a space before `jdbc`. For the other error, see [this faq entry](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/drivers_documentation/java/faq.html#connection-rejected-by-remote-interface-335544421).

Comment: I edit the question and edit URL, and now i get GDS Exception. 335544421. connection rejected by remote interface

Comment: Please make sure you correctly edit your question. You haven't updated the error in your question. And also please specify the Firebird version and the Jaybird version used.

Comment: @Arioch'The That is not correct, `connection rejected by remote interface` means that Firebird accepted the connection, and then terminated it in the handshake because the client asked for unsupported features (in this case probably legacy authentication while wire encryption is required)

Comment: Not directly related to your problem, but why are you still using Jaybird 2.2.5? The latest Jaybird version is 3.0.5, and the latest 2.2.x is 2.2.14.

Comment: That error message looks like one form fbclient.dll, or have you exactly same error texts in JayBird too?  P.S. http://www.sql.ru/forum/interbase

Comment: @Arioch'The It is error `isc_connect_reject`, code `335544421` which Jaybird uses when it doesn't receive an `op_accept`, `op_cond_accept` or `op_accept_data` in response to a connect + attach. Jaybird uses the same errors as Firebird where relevant or appropriate.

Comment: @Arioch'The PS I don't see the point of linking to a Russian forum; I don't read Russian nor does it seem directly relevant here.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel it was for Al-r Zorin who has clearly Russian name. I deleted my comment to him, that originally carried the link. Just did not wanted to spawn an extra comments just for the link. Since there is no clear problem but rather it looks like a novice making first steps and making different mistakes, obvious in retrospect but hard to spot for novices, forum format might be better than SO streamlined Q/A model

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel i use latest avaliable version FireBird 3.0.5 and Jaybird (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.firebirdsql.jdbc/jaybird/2.2.5)

Comment: That is not the latest version. The latest version is Jaybird 3.0.5, see https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:org.firebirdsql.jdbc%20a:jaybird-jdk18 (or https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.firebirdsql.jdbc/jaybird-jdk18/3.0.5) And there is no such thing as Firebird 3.0.5, the latest released Firebird is 3.0.3.

Comment: @Arioch'The In that case it might make more sense to post to the Firebird-Java mailing list.

Comment: I have added new dependency relocation artifacts under `org.firebirdsql.jdbc:jaybird` for 2.2.14 (to `org.firebirdsql.jdbc:jaybird-jdk17:2.2.14`) and 3.0.5 (to `org.firebirdsql.jdbc:jaybird-jdk18:3.0.5`), and will try to do that for future releases.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel and need to add dependency "javax.resource" to jar file

Comment: @AleksandrZorin No, that is already included in the POM for the correct artifact (org.firebirdsql.jdbc:jaybird-jdk17 or jaybird-jdk18). Unless you are not actually using Maven, then yes, you need to include that as described in the documentation.